# Select All Checkbox for Smart tables in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, smart-table

Hey guys so i'm trying to implement a selectall checkbox at the top of my list of checkboxes using a custom directive and i've referred to this thread to do so: https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/270

So far I'm getting an error that says TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. Would really appreciate it if someone can help me out with this one. Thanks

My html:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="document-table" st-table="documents" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <st-select-all all="yourDisplayedCollection"></st-select-all>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="document in documents">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkedDocument"/></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My Directive:

```
.directive('stSelectAll', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected" />',
            scope: {
            all: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.$watch('isAllSelected', function () {
                scope.all.forEach(function (val) {
                val.isSelected = scope.isAllSelected;
                })
            });

            scope.$watch('all', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (oldVal) {
                oldVal.forEach(function (val) {
                    val.isSelected = false;
                });
                }

                scope.isAllSelected = false;
            });
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `yourDisplayedCollection` array's length is actually greater than `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to watch `all`, only `isAllSelected`. Try removing that watch altogether. I'm using the same directive for Smart Table and I don't watch `all`. You also want to add a check to make sure all exists:

```
scope.$watch('isAllSelected', function() {
  if(scope.all) {
    scope.all.forEach(function (val) {
      val.isSelected = scope.isAllSelected;
    }
  }
});
```

Also, you are supposed to make a copy of your original array to use for `st-safe-src` attribute on your table. Then use the original array for your directive.

```
// in your controller (not in your directive)
$scope.yourDisplayedCollection = [].concat($scope.documents);
```

Then change your view.

```
<table id="document-table" st-table="documents" st-safe-src="yourDisplayedCollection" class="table">

<st-select-all all="documents"></st-select-all>
```

Comment: did you get the error that says foreach is undefined?

Comment: Well, you can't get that error any more if you are checking to see if it's defined.

Comment: From looking at the GitHub thread, it looks like you are just not making the array copy. You need to make a copy of the original array to use for your directive AS WELL AS to use for the `st-safe-src` attribute on your table. Not 2 copies, just one copy to use for both.

Comment: hmm so are you saying that i should change my yourDisplayedCollection to documents?

Comment: Yep. And add the `st-safe-src` attribute with your copy to the table tag (if your results are from AJAX). I actually mispoke in my last comment.

Comment: ohhh now im not seeing my data :(...saying that $scope is not defined?

Comment: Haha, that copy statement is supposed to happen in the CONTROLLER, not the directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125205/discussion-between-joelcdoyle-and-jeremy).

Comment: smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 all  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="ctrl.toggleAll(ctrl.all)" ng-model="ctrl.all">
 a    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checks.alpha" ng-value="allChecked">
 b    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checks.beta" ng-value="allChecked">
```

script

```
function MyController() {
    this.data = [
        {title: 'a', data: [1,2,3]},
        {title: 'b', data: [4,5,6]},
        {title: 'c', data: [7,8,9]}
    ];

    let ctrl = this;

    ctrl.checks = {
       alpha: false,
       beta: false
    };

    ctrl.toggleAll = function(toggle) {
        for (let check in ctrl.checks) {
            ctrl.checks[check] = toggle;
        }
   };
   return this;
}
angular.module('test').controller('MyController',MyController);
```

All of the children checkboxes will assume the state of the parent checkbox in this implementation.  Rather than simply toggling the prior state of the child checkbox.

Enjoy. It's has been tested, but feel free to ask if it's broken or you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, modify your directive as

```
function rowSelectAll() {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        $scope: {
            all: '=rowSelectAll',
            selected: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.isAllSelected = false;
            element.bind('click', function (evt) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.all.forEach(function (val) {
                        val.isSelected = $scope.isAllSelected;
                    });
                });
            });

            $scope.$watchCollection('selectedItems', function(newVal) {
                var s = newVal.length;
                var a = ($scope.all !== undefined) ? $scope.all.length : 0;
                if ((s == a) && s > 0 && a > 0) {
                    element.find('input').prop('checked', true);
                    scope.isAllSelected = false;
                } else {
                    element.find('input').prop('checked', false);
                    $scope.isAllSelected = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
app.directive('rowSelectAll', rowSelectAll);
```

And in HTML file, inside table header use your directive and assign table collection i.e, displayedCollection to it.

```
<th row-select-all="displayedCollection" selected-items="selected_items" ng-click="selectAll(displayedCollection)"><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="displayedCollection.length == 0"></th>
```

if you want to selected elements then use the following code:

```
    $scope.selected_items = [];
    // Function to get data for all selected items
    $scope.selectAll = function (collection) {
        // if there are no items in the 'selected_items' array, push all elements to 'selected_items'.
        if ($scope.selected_items.length === 0) {
            angular.forEach(collection, function(val) {
                if (val.bank_flag) {
                    $scope.selected_items.push(val);
                }
          });

        // if there are items in the 'selected_items' array, add only those that are not.
        } else if ($scope.selected_items.length > 0 && $scope.selected_items.length != $scope.displayedCollection.length) {
            angular.forEach(collection, function(val) {

                var found = $scope.selected.indexOf(val);
                if(found == -1) {
                    $scope.selected_items.push(val);
                }

            });
        // Otherwise, reinitiate the variable.
        } else  {
            $scope.selected_items = [];
        }
    };
```